# Pandas identifying if any element is in a row

Tags: pandas, boolean

I have a data frame that is a single row of numerical values and I want to know if any of those values is greater than 2 and if so create a new column with the word 'Diff'

```
    Col_,F_1,F_2
    1,5,0
```

My dataframe is diff_df. Here is one thing I tried

```
    c = diff_df >2
    if c.any():
        diff_df['difference']='Difference'
```

If I were to print c. it would be

```
    Col_,F_1,F_2
    False,True,False
```

I have tried c.all() and many iterations of other things. Clearly my inexperience is holding me back and google is not helping in this regards. Everything I try is either "The truth value of a Series (or Data Frame) is ambiguous use a.any(), a.all()...." Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it is only one row, take the `.max().max()` of the dataframe. With one `.max()` you are going to get the `.max()` of each column. The second `.max()` takes the max of all the columns.

```
if diff_df.max().max() > 2: diff_df['difference']='Difference'
```

output:

```
    Col_ F_1 F_2 difference
0   1    5   0   Difference
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `.loc` accessor and `.gt()` to query and at the same time create new column and populate it

```
df.loc[df.gt(2).any(1), "difference"] = 'Difference'

      Col_  F_1  F_2      difference
 0       1    5    0     Difference
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to David's reponse you may also try this:

```
if ((df > 2).astype(int)).sum(axis=1).values[0] == 1:
    df['difference']='Difference'
```